# Dividing an Input field value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have been trying to calculate an input field value, It is a blockchain project. I want the users to input a certain value or worth of a coin they want to purchase and the system to automatically calculate the amount in Ethereum. For Example when a user input 50000, the system should divide the amount by 10000 and the user will pay 5 Eth.

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  const { addressTo, amount, message } = formData;

  e.preventDefault();

  if ( !amount || !message) return;   

  sendTransaction();
};


<Input placeholder="Address To" name="addressTo" type="hidden" handleChange={handleChange} />
<Input placeholder="Amount (Coin)" name="amount"  type="number" handleChange={handleChange} />
<Input placeholder="Enter Description" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />


await ethereum.request({
  method: "eth_sendTransaction",
  params: [{
    from: currentAccount,
    to: addressTo,
    gas: "0x5208",
    value: parsedAmount._hex,
  }],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
      let formData = {};
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const { addressTo, amount, message } = formData;
      
        e.preventDefault();
      
        if ( !amount || !message) return;   
      
        sendTransaction(formData);
      };
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        let key = e.target.name;
        formData[key] =key === 'amount'?e.target.value/10000: e.target.value ;
        console.log(formData);
      };
      const sendTransaction = async (param) => {
        
        await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_sendTransaction",
          params: [{
            from: param.currentAccount,
            to: param.addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: param.parsedAmount._hex,
          }],
        });
        
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input placeholder="Address To" name="addressTo" type="hidden" onChange={handleChange} />
    <input placeholder="Amount (Coin)" name="amount"  type="number" onChange={handleChange} />
    <input placeholder="Enter Description" name="message" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
    </form>
    </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But it gave an error

Comment: @Nelson can you  provide ss of error

Comment: [ https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-moon-3l2udy ] @Nelson here is the link, you can check it is working and you can see the output in the console.

Comment: kindly check the comment  codesandbox.io/s/zen-moon-3l2udy

Comment: i did not get any comment

Comment: @Nelson can you provide some more code